# 3D tensors expect 2 values for padding Torch

Tags: pytorch, torch

I have succesfully trained and tested my model using [this](https://hackernoon.com/facial-similarity-with-siamese-networks-in-pytorch-9642aa9db2f7) tutorial, and I want to test my model using single images. Here is my code

```
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torchvision.utils
import numpy as np
import random
from PIL import Image
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import PIL.ImageOps    
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim
import torch.nn.functional as F
import os

class Config():
    training_dir = "./data/faces/training/"
    testing_dir = "./data/faces/testing/"
    train_batch_size = 80
    train_number_epochs = 100

class SiameseNetworkDataset(Dataset):
    ...

class SiameseNetwork(nn.Module):
    ...

class ContrastiveLoss(torch.nn.Module):
    ...

if __name__=='__main__':
    net = SiameseNetwork().cuda()
    net.load_state_dict(torch.load("model.pt"))
    img0 = Image.open(os.path.join('data', 'faces', 'testing', 's5', '2.png'))
    img1 = Image.open(os.path.join('data', 'faces', 'testing', 's5', '1.png'))
    img0 = img0.convert("L")
    img1 = img1.convert("L")

    img0 = PIL.ImageOps.invert(img0)
    img1 = PIL.ImageOps.invert(img1)
    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((100,100)),
                                    transforms.ToTensor()
                                    ])
    img0 = transform(img0)
    img1 = transform(img1)
    img0 = img0.cuda()
    img1 = img1.cuda()
    output1,output2 = net(Variable(img0).cuda(),Variable(img1).cuda()) //The error occurred here
    euclidean_distance = F.pairwise_distance(output1, output2)
    print(euclidean_distance.cpu().data.numpy())
```

And I have the following error: `AssertionError: 3D tensors expect 2 values for padding`. I can't understand, what is wrong, because I use the same preprocessing, which is used in SiameseNetworkDataset

Comment: You could perhaps add more information. Which line gives you the error? Have you tried printing the shapes of all your tensors involved? What is the shape of the tensor that's causing the error? etc

Comment: @Ayush the error line is marked with comment: output1,output2 = net(Variable(img0).cuda(),Variable(img1).cuda())

Comment: @Ayush torch.Size([80, 1, 100, 100]) is the size of tensors, used for training, and torch.Size([1, 100, 100]) is my size. Can I somehow change input tensor? I use 80 batch size for training, so maybe this is the case

Comment: You probably need to write `img0.unsqueeze(0).cuda()` and same for img1 and to precise that you're using your model for test like `net.eval()`. As you said in your code `img0.shape: torch.size(1, 100, 100)` you need to add a dimension representing the batch